# Hibernate Mapping between 3 tables

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I need help in entity mapping where 3 tables are involved.

```
table 1: 
table name: emp:- col 1: Id, col 2: name

table 2:
table name: empAddr:- col 1: Id, col 2: empId, col 3: addrId

table 3:
table name: addr:- col 1: Id, col 2: addrLine
```

I have 3 entity classes for each of the above tables.
Could anyone help me with the mapping I need to use?

emp to empAddr is 1 to many

empAddr to addr is 1 to one

Answer (score 0):

in java class

```
table1 will have set<table2> tr2;
table2 will have set<table3> tr3;
```

in xml files

```
  <set name="tr2" table="table2" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="empId" length="20" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="table1" />
        </set>
```